# function not drawing to canvas (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, tkinter, canvas

So I want to make a sorting algorithm visualizer, but something is wrong. The `draw_data(data)` in `bubble_sort` isn't doing anything, while the one in `sort` is working fine. I don't know why. Here's the code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random, winsound


def bubble_sort(data: list):
    n = len(data)

    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
            if data[j] > data[j + 1]:
                data[j], data[j + 1] = data[j + 1], data[j]
            draw_data(data)
            root.after(100)
            winsound.Beep(500, 100)
    print(data)


def draw_data(data):
    canvas.delete("all")
    c_height = 380
    c_width = 600
    x_width = c_width / (len(data) + 1)
    offset = 30
    spacing = 10
    normalized_data = [ i / max(data) for i in data]
    for i, height in enumerate(normalized_data):
        x0 = i * x_width + offset + spacing
        y0 = c_height - height * 340

        x1 = (i + 1) * x_width + offset
        y1 = c_height

        canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="red")
        canvas.create_text(x0+2, y0, anchor=SW, text=str(data[i]))

def sort():
    try:
        max_val = int(max_entry.get())
    except:
        max_val = 10

    try:
        size = int(size_entry.get())
    except:
        size = 10

    if max_val > 100: max_val = 100
    if size > 30 or size < 3: size = 25

    data = []
    for i in range(size):
        data.append(random.randrange(1, max_val + 1))

    draw_data(data)

    root.after(100)
    if alg_box.get() == 'Bubble Sort':
        bubble_sort(data)


root = Tk()
root.title('sort')
root.maxsize(900, 600)
root.config(bg='black')

selected_alg = StringVar()

frame = Frame(root, height=200, width=600, bg='grey')
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

canvas = Canvas(root, width=600, height=380)
canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

Label(frame, text='Algorithm: ', bg='grey').grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, sticky=W)
alg_box = ttk.Combobox(frame, textvariable=selected_alg, values=['Bubble Sort'])
alg_box.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5)
Button(frame, text='Sort', command=sort, bg='purple').grid(row=0, column=3, pady=5)

Label(frame, text='Array Size: ', bg='grey').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
size_entry = Entry(frame)
size_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5, sticky=W)

Label(frame, text='Max Value: ', bg='grey').grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)
max_entry = Entry(frame)
max_entry.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

You should be focusing on this part of the code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random, winsound


def bubble_sort(data: list):
    n = len(data)

    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
            if data[j] > data[j + 1]:
                data[j], data[j + 1] = data[j + 1], data[j]
            draw_data(data)
            root.after(100)
            winsound.Beep(500, 100)
    print(data)


def draw_data(data):
    canvas.delete("all")
    c_height = 380
    c_width = 600
    x_width = c_width / (len(data) + 1)
    offset = 30
    spacing = 10
    normalized_data = [ i / max(data) for i in data]
    for i, height in enumerate(normalized_data):
        x0 = i * x_width + offset + spacing
        y0 = c_height - height * 340

        x1 = (i + 1) * x_width + offset
        y1 = c_height

        canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="red")
        canvas.create_text(x0+2, y0, anchor=SW, text=str(data[i]))

def sort():
    try:
        max_val = int(max_entry.get())
    except:
        max_val = 10

    try:
        size = int(size_entry.get())
    except:
        size = 10

    if max_val > 100: max_val = 100
    if size > 30 or size < 3: size = 25

    data = []
    for i in range(size):
        data.append(random.randrange(1, max_val + 1))

    draw_data(data)

    root.after(100)
    if alg_box.get() == 'Bubble Sort':
        bubble_sort(data)
```

DETAILS:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8

Comment: Maybe try force the GUI to update with `root.update_idletasks()` at the end of `draw_data()`.

Comment: This line `root.after(100)` is doing nothing. Also put out `draw_data` out of your *forloop*. After this, check your math because I think, whatever it should do, it does it wrong.

Comment: @Atlas435 I think the reason why `draw_data` is in the for loop is to visualize the sorting process step by step (hence the pause between each step). When I add `root.update_idletasks()` at the end in `draw_data()`, the code seems to work fine, I can see the animation of the sorting process.

Comment: @j_4321 since OP is using an arry in `draw_data` it draws more rectangels that intended. Also if I'm using value 5 and 10 it works, but try 1 and 2, you get an huge array as output.

Comment: @Atlas435 Thanks for pointing that out I hadn't realized

Comment: @j_4321 You are welcome. I'm just curious about the topic *function not drawing to canvas (tkinter)* I guess debugging informations are missing here.

Comment: @Atlas435 I have just realized that in `sort()`, sizes smaller than 3 get set to 25, so this is why you had a big array output and it is an intended behavior, not a bug.

Comment: @j_4321 You are right, I missed that. Thank you.

Comment: @j_4321 ```root.update_idletasks``` worked! Please post it as an answer so I can verify it.

Comment: Nevermind, it created a new problem. Now when I click off of the window and go back to it, the program doesn't respond and it doesn't do the animations.